# How to test a class full of constants

Tags: c#, java, unit-testing, testing

There is a class in my project which is just constants as follows:

```
public class AppConstants
{
  public static String Foo = "Foo";
  public static String Bar = "Bar";
  // so on...
}
```

Ok these can be marked `readonly/final` etc.

How can i test this class or make it testable? same idea for a `Enum` ?

I dont see anything to test but for the sake of testability how can i improve it?

Comment: What actually needs testing in this class?

Comment: Why would you test it?  What could possibly go wrong?  There is no logic to test.

Comment: @EdS. i can mark it as final or readonly for java and c# correspondingly. but i thought that s kinda irrelevant.

Comment: I would just create an interface of properties, and make an implementation which returns a constant value.

Comment: @DarthVader yes, it's slightly irrelevant, but you should use `const` (look it up if you need to) instead of `static` for constant literals.

Comment: @DarthVader: It becomes relevant when someone writes `AppConstants.Foo = "Ruh Roh";`  Just mark them as `const`

Comment: I would just use an attribute like [ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute] on this class to stop it from getting picked up by the coverage tool.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What is there to test?  So you have a class full of public, static variables (those are not constant, regardless of the name of the class)... there is no logic here.  As long as the compiler knows how to generate valid bytecode (it does) and as long as the CLR knows how to interpret said bytecode (it does), there is no problem.

Comment: well the reason i was asking it the code coverage as this code shows as not being covered. then the question comes to how do i hide this class from code coverage?

Comment: @DarthVader, You don't need 100% code coverage, it's a myth.  You just need enough coverage to be confident.

Comment: You can exclude the file from the coverage process too.